# Fillna() depending on another column

Tags: pandas, fillna

I want to do next:
Fill DF1 NaN with values from DF2 depending on column value in DF1.

Basically, DF1 has people with "income_type" and some NaN in "total_income". In DF2 there are "median income" for each "income_type". I want to fill NaN in "total_income" DF1 with median values from DF2
[DF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7uSz.png), [DF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDlsg.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would merge values from DF2 to DF1 by 'income_type'

```
DF3 = DF1.merge(DF2, how='left', on='income_type')
```

This way you have the values of median income and total income in the same dataframe.
After this, I would do an if else statement for a pandas dataframe columns

```
DF3.loc[DF3['total_income'].isna(), 'total_income'] = DF3['median income']
```

That will replace the NaN values with the median values from the merge

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two dataframes and then replace the nan values with the median. Here is a similar working example. Cheers mate.

```
import pandas as pd

#create the example dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'income_type':['a','b','c','a','a','b','b'], 'total_income':[200, 300, 500,None,400,None,None]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'income_type':['a','b','c'], 'median_income':[205, 305, 505]})

# inner join the df1 with df2 on the column 'income_type'
joined = df1.merge(df2, on='income_type')

# fill the nan values the value from the column 'median_income' and save it in a new column 'total_income_not_na'
joined['total_income_not_na'] = joined['total_income'].fillna(joined['median_income'])
print(joined)
```